# Do I need to hold atleast 1 viewmodel that will handle all of my views?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

for example I have several views with viewmodel for each view, then my mainviewmodel will handle all those views for me to navigate or load it to mainwindow. Did I bypass the rules of MVVM? because of having a mainviewmodel that knows about all my views?

Comment: I don't think so... It is the same as having a View (Window) with several SubViews (User Controls or Controls), isn't it?
I don't think that the way you structure your ViewModel hierarchically does violate the MVVM pattern...

Comment: thanks Fleve, I get your point. But my mainviewmodel now can't stand without those subviews right? and I think that was my violation regarding the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Well I hope I get your point as we... I think that you will always have to know how the ViewModel is organized to bind it in your View. The problem with "organization in the view is depending on the organization in the ViewModel" can always exist...

Comment: just for clarification sir Fleve, how did you manage the navigation of other views from MainViewModel to rendered it into MainView (mainwindow)? did you create an instance of other views inside your MainViewModel and set it to the properties that bounded to the content of MainWindow? TIA.

Comment: Lets see an example: Model with Class Planet which contains the Properties Name and Composition. Composition is a container of Element and other things the user does not need to see/edit. 
My MainViewModel (PlanetViewModel) would be composed of NameViewModel and CompositionViewModel... a string and a list of strings cause the user use a text controls to see and edit planets.
My View has a Window (PlanetView) and two Controls. I just set to View a binding to a PlanetViewModel and the binding context of the Controls hierarchically.... You can use UserControls also if you want.

Comment: So you create a one model that holds all of your usercontrol or 'composition' together with its name, then your mainviewmodel will be composed of that model, then your mainview content are bound to that model as properties of mainviewmodel? thanks Fleve..

Comment: That's exactly the whole point of MVVM. Ask yourself a simple question: "Can I run my entire application without creating a single view?" If the answer is "yes" then you've probably done it properly. If you've correctly separated your view models from your views then your entire application should be capable of running normally by simply injecting the messages and bindings that the views would otherwise be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways of approaching MVVM design: view-first and viewmodel-first. Although they are both valid, they have their ups and downs. And both make sure that the **viewmodels do not depend on the views** in any way, only views depend on the viewmodels. Your solution is valid MVVM, but causes circular dependencies between the view and viewmodel layers. So I would suggest sticking with either

## View-first

You start with your MainWindow.xaml and design it as you like. You instantiate a viewmodel for each window/dialog/control in your view code by adding

```
<MainWindow.DataContext>
  <vm:MainViewModel>
</MainWindow.DataContext>
```

into the XAML and start binding all your state so you can move behavior into that MainViewModel class.

The pro-version of this approach uses a dependency-injection container ([autofac](http://autofac.org/), [ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), etc.) to instantiate the MainViewModel without the MainWindow actually knowing about the concrete type of the viewmodel.

## Viewmodel-first

In the [bootstrapper](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), you somehow set the MainWindow.DataContext with an instance of its viewmodel, but otherwise you rely on DataTemplate to instantiate views (cannot instantiate Window using a DataTemplate, sorry).

Each bindable property in a viewmodel can be bound to a ContentPresenter, each bindable collection in a viewmodel can be bount to a subclass of ItemPresenter (ListBox, ComboBox, whatever) and you are almost done.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. Appreciated.